# What's the equivalent of Router.events in the app router next/navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When using the app router, using the `next/navigation` package, is there an equlivent to `next/router`'s Router.events object?

I am trying to build a loading progress bar that will show whenever a user navigates from one page to another,

using the old pages router, we can do:

```js
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress'; // or any other progress bar library

    const start = () => NProgress.start();
    const done = () => NProgress.done();

    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', start);
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', done);
    Router.events.on('routeChangeError', done);
```

How to apply the same effect with the app router?